# how to get id after change the owl carousel side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, owl-carousel

Hello I want to get current id after change the side. Right now it is on change but getting previous id of slide.

JS

```
hometopowl.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(event) {
var activeMenu = $(".body-top-slider-container .owl-carousel").find(".owl-item.active").find(".item").attr('data-hash');
alert(activeMenu);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var activeMenu = $(".body-top-slider-container .owl-carousel").find(".owl-item .active").find(".item").attr('data-hash');
```

Try this

Comment: no it is same as i wrote. in fact it say 'undefined'.

Comment: actually i want to drag the slider want to get the next or previous data-hase

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the documentation of Owl Carousel [here](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/owlStatus.html) ?

Remy